# Using Linq to find array with the largest length

Tags: c#, linq

I need to find the largest array in a list of arrays.
Using basic techniques, I can do this

```
        List<int[]> intArrayList;
        ...
        int largestArrayIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < intArrayList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (intArrayList[largestArrayIndex].Length < 
                intArrayList[i].Length)
            {
                largestArrayIndex = i;
            }
        }
```

But, I'm curious if there's a more succinct method of doing this with Linq?
And, would there be any performance differences between the two?

**Edit:**  I want the largest array.  So, if I have a list of { int[5], int[7], int[9], int[3] } I want the index or reference to the int[9] array.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to know the maximum length, or do you want to return the longest array ?

Comment: Guys come on. He is clearly saying that he wants to find _the largest array_ (the one with the most elements) in a list of arrays. And his example find the index of the largest array. (granted.. The title is a bit misleading)

Answer (score 5):

You could do this:

```
var longest = intArrayList.Aggregate((i1,i2) => i1.Length > i2.Length ? i1 : i2);
```

Performance wise, it will only iterate the list once, so I'd say it's pretty much the same as your code.

EDIT: Just wanted to clarify that my code returns the longest array, not the longest length.

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```
int[] longestArray =  intArrayList.OrderBy(x => x.Length).Last();
```

It returns the longest array. If you need an index of the longest array, then:

```
int index = intArrayList.Select((x,i) => new {Length = x.Length, Index = i}).OrderBy(x => x.Length).Last().Index;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't compile.

Comment: Although it is correct I wouldn't recommend this one. It has O(nlog(n)) complexity because of sorting, which isn't necessary. Using `int len = intArray.Max(arr => arr.Length)` and then `int[] longest = intArray.First(arr => arr.Length == len)` is faster for any array bigger than 10 items and has O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the original method is good. The following code should do the same:

```
int maxLen = int.MinValue;
int maxLenIndex = intArrayList.SelectMany((array, index) => array.Length > maxLen && ((maxLen = array.Length) > int.MinValue) ? new[] { index } : new int[0]).Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

This one runs in O(n) time but you need to have at least one array in the list.

```
int lengthOfLongest = intArrayList.Max(arr => arr.Length);
// For the array
int[] longestArray = intArrayList.First(arr => arr.Length == lengthOfLongest);
// For the index
int indexOfLongest = intArrayList.FindIndex(arr => arr.Length == lengthOfLongest);
```